# Can two side by side directives communicate with each other in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had such html code

```
<a href="#" id="someLink">
    <i class="someClass"></i><span>Some span text</span>
</a>
<div id="dependsOnSomeLink">
    <!-- something here -->
</div>
```

that I wanted to separate into directives in AngularJS. The logic behind it was, that contents of `div` is hidden by default and is shown by click on `a` element.

I wanted to separate that into two directives like that:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
  .directive('prAbc', function($log) {
    return {
      require: 'prDef',
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<a href="#" id="someLink"><i class="someClass"></i><span>Some span text</span></a>',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        // do the harlem share <-- here
      },
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, prDef, transcludeFn) {
        iElement.bind('click', function() {
          prDef.toggleDependentBlock();
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('prDef', function($log)
  {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div id="dependsOnSomeLink"></div>',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        $scope.showDependentBlock = false;

        this.toggleDependentBlock = function() {
          $scope.showDependentBlock = false === $scope.showDependentBlock;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

and later use it like that

```
<pr-abc></pr-abc>
<pr-def></pr-def>
```

But `prDef` is not defined when it is called from `prAbc` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require: 'prDef'` works when `prAbc` and `prDef` are applied on the same DOM element, which is not your case.

What you may need is "parent" directive which will act as a router between the two communicating directives. `prDef` registers itself to the parent controller and `prAbc` calls the parent controller which, in turn, calls `prDef`.

Check out this [plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6wKo9zuZT61bDx4UWiNM?p=preview).

There are at least 3 other options to consider:

1. Have the parent controller listen to specific events that `prAbc` emits and broadcasts them downwards, where `prDef` listens on.
2. Have the parent controller pass callback functions (`'&'`) to the child directives for registration and routing.
3. All functions and data is defined on the parent and passed to child directives through binding or prototypal inheritance (essentially, ruin your design :P).

For all 3 options, the parent controller does not have to be defined in a directive, it can be any controller which you apply like:

```
<div ng-contoller="ParentCtrl">
    <pr-abc></pr-abc>
    <pr-def></pr-def>
</div>
```

Your example does not provide enough context to reason which option is the best, but I think the parent directive should be the preferred way to go.

If it helps, checkout how ui-bootstrap's [tabs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js) and [accordion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js) are implemented. It's a very helpfull example of collaborating, still decoupled, set of directives.

Comment: Very interesting solution you proposed in plunked. Thank you. Regarding other suggestions. 1) I thought about events as well, but it seems to me, that it would brake logic behind directives. 2) Not sure I understand.

Comment: option 2 is something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/5waOuKJG4RbAzfTZTG8B?p=preview). Not my favourite, but still, it does the job.